# My code isnt recognising a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

- Im new to python so ignore small mistakes <3
- I wanted to make the program start without user input, so i set start to true, and had the start up function run when it was true. However if the user enters true to run the main program it becomes an error and says main() is not defined.

  ```
  start = True

  while start:
      print("Hello world!")
      name=input("Please enter your name: ")
      print("Hi {0}".format(name))
      run=input("type | True | to run the program: ").capitalize()
      if run== "True":
          print("Program is starting..")
          main()
          start = False
      else:
          print("You need to enter | True | to run the program")
          start = True

  def main():

      print("1 = Add")
      print("2 = Subtract")
      print("3 = Times")
      print("4 = Divide")
      print("5 = Quit program")
      calc=int(input("enter number of choise: "))
  ```
- And heres the error:

  ```
  Hello world!
  Please enter your name: pls no
  Hi pls no
  type | True | to run the program: true
  Program is starting..
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\chemg\Documents\calculator.py", line 11, in <module>
          main()
  NameError: name 'main' is not defined
  ```

Comment: FYI, it is more common (and arguable more readable) to use `while True` and simply `break` when you want to stop the iteration, rather than setting a variable value unless you use that variable in some outter scope later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `main` before `while start`. You're referring to a function that is not yet defined.

Answer (score 1):

You define main after the first call. Usually you first define all your functions and then do stuff with them.

```
def main():

  print("1 = Add")
  print("2 = Subtract")
  print("3 = Times")
  print("4 = Divide")
  print("5 = Quit program")
  calc=int(input("enter number of choise: "))

start = True

while start:
  print("Hello world!")
  name=input("Please enter your name: ")
  print("Hi {0}".format(name))
  run=input("type | True | to run the program: ").capitalize()
  if run== "True":
    print("Program is starting..")
    main()
    start = False
  else:
    print("You need to enter | True | to run the program")
    start = True
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Python scripts are executed top to bottom. When you enter your main loop, the main function is not defined. Swap the order of them around.

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter reads and executes your script sequentially. When your code reaches the point where it calls the function main, it has not yet been read and is thus not known to the interpreter at that point.

To fix it, place the function above the point where you call it (in your case, before 'start = True'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to move the function block up.  The program can't recognize main() because, at the time it's called inside your while loop, it hasn't been defined yet.

Try this:

```
def main():
    print("1 = Add")
    print("2 = Subtract")
    print("3 = Times")
    print("4 = Divide")
    print("5 = Quit program")
    calc=int(input("enter number of choise: "))

start = True

while start:
    print("Hello world!")
    name=input("Please enter your name: ")
    print("Hi {0}".format(name))
    run=input("type | True | to run the program: ").capitalize()
    if run== "True":
        print("Program is starting..")
        main()
        start = False
    else:
        print("You need to enter | True | to run the program")
        start = True
```